# Undefined function 'mex_pb_parts_final_selected' for input arguments of type 'double'

Tags: matlab

I am working on Contour Detection and Image Segmentation Resources. When i run the pre-compile matlab package on windows10, I am getting the following errors,

Undefined function 'mex_pb_parts_final_selected' for input arguments of type 'double'.

Error in det_mPb (line 6)
textons, ...

> Error in multiscalePb (line 24) [bg1, bg2, bg3, cga1, cga2, cga3,
>   cgb1, cgb2, cgb3, tg1, tg2, tg3, textons] = det_mPb(im);
>
> Error in globalPb (line 39) [mPb, mPb_rsz, bg1, bg2, bg3, cga1, cga2,
>   cga3, cgb1, cgb2, cgb3, tg1, tg2, tg3, textons] = multiscalePb(im,
>   rsz);

About the project details, https://www2.eecs.berkeley.edu/Research/Projects/CS/vision/grouping/resources.html

As i am new to this, any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: so two options: you don't have in your matlab's folder the function mex_pb_parts_final_selected or  mex_pb_parts_final_selected don't support your input. But i think that you just need to add this function in your folder...

Comment: Are you using the pre-compiled version? If not you will need to compile the mex files.

Comment: The project is not implemented in windows?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same problem with windows 10, Matlab2016a.

Comment: failed in windows too,but successed in Linux.